# Differentiability in $\mathbb R^3$

Tags: analysis, derivatives

$G$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R^3$ and $(a,b,c)$ belongs to $G$. $f$ is a function from $G$ to $R$.

i) Define: $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b,c)$

ii) Prove if $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b,c)$ then the partial derivatives exist at $(a,b,c)$

Should i imitate the definition of $f$ is differentiable at $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb R^2$: there should exist two real numbers $c$ and $d$ such that: $f(a+h,b+k)=f(a,b)+ch+dk+r(h,k)$ where 
$\lim r(h,k)/\sqrt{h^2+k^2}$ while $(h,k)$ is going to zero

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: concerning the second part any hint would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable, then there is a linear map $L\in \mathcal L(\Bbb R^3,\Bbb R)$ such that 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h_1,b+h_2,c+h_3)-f(a,b,c)+L(h_1,h_2,h_3)}{\|h\|}=0.$$
where $h=(h_1,h_2,h_3)$.
In particular

$$\lim_{h_1\to 0}\frac{f(a+h_1,b,c)-f(a,b,c)+L(h_1,0,0)}{h_1}=0$$

with $h_1\mapsto L(h_1,0,0)\in \mathcal L(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$. Therefore $x\mapsto f(x,b,c)$ is differentiable at $x=a$ and thus $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(a,b,c)$ exists. Do the same for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_3}$ and you'll get the result.